# INDEX MATCH with multiple criteria that aren't exact matches without using array

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match

I'm trying to rewrite the following without having to use an array (processing time is currently so slow it's nearly impossible to do anything in this workbook):

```
{=INDEX('Sheet1'!$F:$F,MATCH(1,('Sheet2'!$C5='Sheet1'!$C:$C)*('Sheet2'!$F5='Sheet1'!$E:$E)*('Sheet1'!$A:$A>='Sheet2'!$A5)*('Sheet1'!$A:$A<='Sheet2'!$B5),0))}
```

Sheet1: A = Start Date; C = Name; E = Project; F = Hours

Sheet2: A = Start Date; B = End Date; C = Name; F = Project

I've considered concatenating 'Start Date'&'Name'&'Project', but that won't work because the dates between the two sheets aren't necessarily exact matches - Sheet1 Start and End Dates typically fall within the Start and End Dates on Sheet2 but don't always encompass the same exact ranges.

Comment: one thing to remember about array formulas, limit the references to only the data set,  DO NOT use full column references.  That alone will make a huge difference in the time to calculate. as it will cut out millions of calculations per formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since hours are numbers, use SUMIFS()

```
=SUMIFS('Sheet1'!$F:$F,'Sheet1'!$C:$C,'Sheet2'!$C5,'Sheet1'!$E:$E,'Sheet2'!$F5,'Sheet1'!$A:$A,">=" & 'Sheet2'!$A5,'Sheet1'!$A:$A,"<=" &'Sheet2'!$B5)
```

Comment: Wowwwwww I really overthought this one. That's exactly what I needed. Thanks!!